# Phonegap 3.0, Android - On invocation of WebIntent plugin, getting Class not found exception

Tags: cordova, webintents

I am working with Phonegap 3.0. I have included in the config.xml : 
    gap:plugin name="com.borismus.webintent

and in index.html script 
    type="text/javascript" src="webintent.js"

I am getting error - 'Mail Form: sendMail failed via Android Intent: class not found' 
when run in Android

Below is the code:

```
var extras = {};
extras[window.plugins.webintent.EXTRA_EMAIL] =   "vidya.narasimhan@merceworld.com";
extras[window.plugins.webintent.EXTRA_TEXT] = "hello testing";
console.log('Mail Form: starting webintent activity  ');
window.plugins.webintent.startActivity(
     { 
            action: window.plugins.webintent.ACTION_SEND,
            type: 'application/octet-stream', 
            extras: extras 
     }, 
     function() {
            console.log('Mail Form: sendMail success via Android Intent');
     }, 
     function(e) {
            console.log('Mail Form: sendMail failed via Android Intent:' + e);
     }
```

);

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of WebIntent, I used FileOpener.

don's FileOpener version have worked on my app cordova 3.0

```
phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/don/FileOpener
```

all the xmls, plugin, etc are then added automatically.

added **fileopener.js** on index.html
and then

```
window.plugins.fileOpener.open( path );
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, your webintent will be working correctly on the android emulator or the device but you may get this error when you check with `serve` on your phonegap app. Check on the device or the simulator once!